# Lower Riemann integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am reading Elements of Integration by Bartle and I came across this:

> If f is a bounded function defined on an interval $[a,b]$ and if $f$ is not too discontinuous […] In particular the lower Riemann integral of $f$ may be defined to be the supremum of the integrals of all step functions $\gamma$ such that $\gamma (x) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $\gamma (x)=0$ for $x \notin [a,b]$.

If it is the lower sum, should it not be the infimum?

Answer (score 3):

If $\gamma \le f$, then the integral of $\gamma$ (called a lower sum) is a lower bound for any reasonable definition of the integral of $f$. The *supremum* of all lower sums is in a sense the best lower bound. This is by definition the lower Riemann integral.

Comment: In other words, each lower sum is obtained through an infimum operation; we then take the supremum of the infima. This "maximin" or "minimax" procedure is a common situation in analysis.